# Justify why there are no non-constant periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm probably missing something stupid here, regarding periodic solutions to ODE's.

The ode is $$\dot{x}=-\nabla f$$

I can see that a solution will require $\frac{df}{dt}=-\|\nabla f\|^2$. Buy why does this prevent existence of such solutions?

More generally, why are we interested in the behavior of $f$ rather than $x$?

Comment: What does $df/dt$ mean? And where did you get $\nabla^2 f$?

Comment: @TedShifrin This was of course a typo. Is that better now? I simply used the chain rule and used the equation. .

Answer (score 3):

For any solution you get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=f'(x(t))\dot x(t)=-f'(x(t))∇f(x(t))=-\|∇f(x(t))\|^2
$$
so that either the solution is stationary or decreases the level of $f$, preventing the return to a previous point.

Comment: Could you explain the last sentence a bit more? This is the part I don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: Particularly, why are we looking at the behavior of $f$ rather than the behavior of $x$?

Comment: The only thing that we know about $x$ is its connection to $f$. One of the few things that one can do is then measure $x$ by its function values of $f$. And indeed you get the nice descent property of the gradient flow which makes it interesting in the first place.